# list_empty is returning true after some iteration.

Tags: linux, linked-list, v4l2

I'm writing V4L2 driver by referring vivi.c driver from linux kernel 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.17/source/drivers/media/platform/vivi.c#L875

```
static void vivi_thread_tick(struct vivi_dev *dev)
{
    struct vivi_dmaqueue *dma_q = &dev->vidq;
    struct vivi_buffer *buf;
    unsigned long flags = 0;

    dprintk(dev, 1, "Thread tick\n");

    spin_lock_irqsave(&dev->slock, flags);
    if (list_empty(&dma_q->active)) {
        dprintk(dev, 1, "No active queue to serve\n");
        spin_unlock_irqrestore(&dev->slock, flags);
        return;
    }

    buf = list_entry(dma_q->active.next, struct vivi_buffer, list);
    list_del(&buf->list);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&dev->slock, flags);

    v4l2_get_timestamp(&buf->vb.v4l2_buf.timestamp);

    /* Fill buffer */
    vivi_fillbuff(dev, buf);
    dprintk(dev, 1, "filled buffer %p\n", buf);

    vb2_buffer_done(&buf->vb, VB2_BUF_STATE_DONE);
    dprintk(dev, 2, "[%p/%d] done\n", buf, buf->vb.v4l2_buf.index);
}
```

In vivi_thread_tick() function as shown above,if (list_empty(&dma_q->active)) becomes true after some itration. Because of this, in dmesg -w "No active queue to serve" is displayed.

After debugging the code, it looks like dma_q->active.next and dma_q->active.prev are pointing to same address.  Head, Head->next and Head->prev address are given below:

```
Sl No   Head            Head->next       Hear->prev       vb2_buffer->index
1      FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
2      FFF03C05E8       FFEEEB19E8      FFF03C05E8             1
3      FFF03C0DE8       FFF03C05E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
4      FFF03C19E8       FFF03C0DE8      FFF03C19E8             3
5      FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
6      FFF03C05E8       FFEEEB19E8      FFF03C05E8             1
7      FFF03C0DE8       FFF03C05E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
8      FFF03C19E8       FFF03C0DE8      FFF03C19E8             3
9      FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
10     FFF03C05E8       FFEEEB19E8      FFF03C05E8             1
11     FFF03C0DE8       FFF03C05E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
12     FFF03C19E8       FFF03C0DE8      FFF03C19E8             3
13     FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
14     FFF03C05E8       FFEEEB19E8      FFF03C05E8             1
15     FFF03C0DE8       FFF03C05E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
16     FFF03C19E8       FFF03C0DE8      FFF03C19E8             3
17     FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
18     FFF03C05E8       FFEEEB19E8      FFF03C05E8             1
19     FFF03C0DE8       FFF03C05E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
20     FFF03C19E8       FFF03C0DE8      FFF03C19E8             3
21     FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             0
22     FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFEEEB19E8             1
23     FFC09637B0       FFF03C19E8      FFF03C0DE8             2
24     FFF03C19E8       FFF03C19E8      FFF03C19E8             3
25     FFEEF038E8       FFEEF038E8      FFEEF038E8
```

As you can see serial number 24 and 25, Head->next and Head->prev are same. Because of this (list_empty(&dma_q->active)) is true .

Queries:
why after some iteration, Head->next and Head->prev are pointing to same address ?